# Matrix Differential Equation with a Skew-Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

From a bank of masters exams:

> Say the position of a particle moving
>   in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by a smooth
>   vector-valued function $\vec{x}(t)$.
>   Suppose that $\vec{x}(t)$ satisfies a
>   differential equation,
>   $$ \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A(t)\vec{x},$$
>     where $A(t)$ is a
>   real anti-symmetric matrix depending
>   smoothly on $t$. Show that this
>   particle moves on a sphere, that is,
>   $||\vec{x}(t)||$ is constant.

By the spectral theorem, $A$ is normal and therefore has a complete basis of eigenvectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I am familiar with the "standard" method of solving for matrix exponentials, i.e. finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, and then using linear combinations of $e^{\lambda t}\vec{x}$ as the solutions, but there is not a complete basis of eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}$. Taking the matrix exponential $e^A$ doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: just compute the time derivative of $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}$

Comment: user8268 is right. in order to prove $\|x\|$ is constant, just compute its derivative with respect to time. $\|x\|^2=x^Tx$, $dx^Tx=2x^Tdx=2x^TAxdt$. Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, $x^TAx=0$

Comment: @Shiyu or user8268: could you explain the differentiation step $d(x^Tx) = 2x^Tdx$? I don't quite understand how differentiation interacts with the transpose.

Comment: please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking from [user8268](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8268/user8268) and [Shiyu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7156/shiyu):

Compute the time derivative of $||\vec{x}||^2 = \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}$, which becomes

$ \begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} ||\vec{x}||^2 &= \frac{d}{dt} (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}) 
\\ &= \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} \cdot \vec{x} + \vec{x} \cdot \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} 
\\ &= 2 \left( \vec{x} \cdot \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} \right)
\\ &= 2 \left( \vec{x} \cdot A \vec{x} \right)
\\ &= 2 \left( \vec{x}^T A \vec{x} \right) = 2(0) = 0
\end{align} $

The last line is true because $\vec{x}^TA\vec{x} = 0$ for all $\vec{x}$ if $A$ is skew-symmetric. Therefore $||\vec{x}||^2$ is constant, implying that $||\vec{x}|| \geq 0$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Skew-symmetric matrices have pure imaginary eigenvalues (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix). This means that the matrix will rotate a vector by $\pi/2$ (for odd dimensions there is also a 0 eigenvalue).  This implies that the direction of change is always perpendicular to position.  Sounds like a sphere to me.

Comment: Do you know the solution of that ODE

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: I am facing same issue. It occurred to me while solving following problem in the link. Please click [HERE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976094/infinite-series-psis-psi0-psi-10s-psi-20-fracs22-psi-30) for stack exchange  link. Equation (2) in the link is the example. If I can solve that ODE,it will be very helpful. That ODE in eq 2 is in same format as in this question. Thanks